# Configure POST endpoint to respond only to cron.yaml requests

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I have a Django app running on Elastic Beanstalk and want to run a job every night (reindex of search engine). According to [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html) I can use `cron.yaml` to automatically make `POST` requests to my app at the right time, and configure my app to respond appropriately.

How can I ensure my app only responds to the auto-generated requests, and not random requests to the same URL? Specifically, I don't want malicious users posting and causing the app to do things.

Comment: Surely you can just check in the view that the request is a POST?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to stop a malicious user from POSTing as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check several things to make sure the request is coming from `cron.yaml`...

1) The request will be coming from `localhost`.

2) The `User-Agent` will include `aws-sqsd`.

3) The request should only be handled by your worker instance.

I use `before_action` filters to enforce these in my controller. The code looks something like this:

```
##
# Protect against abuse - requests must have the correct "User-Agent" header,
# come from localhost, and will only be handled by worker instances.
before_action :correct_user_agent
before_action :correct_source
before_action :worker_instance

...controller code here...

private

##
# Confirms the correct User-Agent header was sent.
def correct_user_agent
  return if request.headers.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].include?("aws-sqsd")
  head(:forbidden)
end

##
# Confirms the request is coming from localhost.
def correct_source
  return if request.local? || Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
  head(:forbidden)
end

##
# Don't allow requests to be processed in the production web environment, since
# it has a worker instance associated with it.
def worker_instance
  return unless Rails.env.production?
  head(:forbidden)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. 2 can be trivially faked; 1 probably can't due to TCP handshake but seems risky (not sure how Django handles `X-FORWARDED-FOR` etc); 3 is relying on ELB not sending traffic to the worker instance (can I rely on that?)

Comment: If you've configured the load balancer correctly, it should only know about the web instances.